# How to auto-fill blank cells of the column with the last populated value in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

In a column, various entries are present with the gap of 2 or 3 blank cells. How to populate the last entry?

Example:

```
        Column A
1      COKE
2
3
4
5      SPRITE
6
7
8      DUKE
9
10
```

`A2` `A3` `A4` populates `COKE`, `A6` `A7` populates `SPRITE` and `A9` `A10` populates `DUKE`. As sheet contains thousands of entries , can't do it manually.
Tried various combinations with `IF`, `VLOOKUP`, `LEN` etc. but not able to figure out.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P787-9L5NFdoYRueLlB8MtVrOcMNYRSt3HmvpdqAbcc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

- on spot (meaning in the same column) you can do **`=REPT(A1; 1)`** in **A2** cell and then copy **A2** selection and paste to every empty cell

  [image]
- in next column you can do simple **`IF()`** like:

  - B1: **`=A1`**
  - B2: **`=IF(A2=""; B1; A2)`** and drag down

  [image]